# getting the text from a TextView from a different activiy

Tags: java, android, android-activity, textview

I have 2 activities: Activity_A and Activity_B. On Activity_A I have a TextView with the id "MyTextView". How can I get its text from Avtivity_B?
I have tried to do this in Activity_B main Java file:

```
txtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MyTextView);
txtv.getText().toString()
```

But this didn't work.
Is there any way to this without Intents?

Comment: get the text in Activity a and pass it to activity b

Comment: Make the TextView visible through your project, so that other classes can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge is that when an activity is not visible, it has been paused, and is no longer available. Also the id used in findViewById may refer to an id in the other activities layout file. Using an intent to pass the data when moving between activities is a good solution, or if you really need access to that data from different activities you could store it in shared preferences, in a database, or as a static field on the activity class itself.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer!! It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the content on the Activity where you have it and then send data from activity A to activity B with the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("fromActivityA",textView.getText());
```

And then you have to use getExtra() method on activity B for getting the data you send from activity A.

Hope you can find this helpful!